# Weird stringstream behavior when extracting and inserting multiple times.

Tags: c++, stringstream

Can someone help me understand this stringstream behavior?

```
stringstream temp;
temp << "342 1 ";
int a;
while (temp >> a) {
    cout << a << endl;
}
temp << "56" << " ";
temp >> a;
cout << a << endl;
```

Which outputs:

```
342
1
1
```

I would expect it to output

```
342
1
56
```

This was compiled in visual studios 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have read the value 1, the next `while` will reach end-of-file and put the stream in an error state. Any further reads will then fail, and leave `a` unchanged.

You can clear the error state by calling `temp.clear()`.

Comment: In addition to calling `clear()` to reset the state: any input should be checked for success. If the source is absolutely controlled by the program that may be overkill but I doubt that it really is as assigning `56` directly would be more effective.